# Rake, how to create a task with multiple inputs and one output?

Tags: ruby, rake

We have a rails app, and we use webpack which takes multiple javascript files and outputs one single javascript file. It takes a long time to run, and I'd like to create a rake task for this. But being new to rake I need some help.

I'd like to use rake's build system so that I can get automatic checking of the time stamps between the input and output .js files. So that if **any** of the input files are newer than the output file it will execute webpack. Otherwise if the **none** of the input files are newer than the output file, than the task does nothing.

In MSBuild, this is a cakewalk and lightning fast. But in Ruby I'm kind of lost.

I'm guessing it might consist of writing file tasks, and looping through and making the one output file depend on the inputs. Or should I use a rule, like this?

```
outputfile = "~/foo.js"
inputfiles = Dir["~/**/*.js"]

rule outputfile => inputfiles do
  bin/webpack bla bla bla
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Rake::FileList`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/rake/rdoc/Rake/FileList.html) to achieve this. Something like this:

```
file "foo.js" => Rake::FileList["**/*.js"] do
  ...
end
```

And, I'm not sure whether rake allows to use `~` in paths, I believe a full path is required. Or just use a `"#{Dir.home}/foo.js"` rule.

Then call it using:

```
rake ~/foo.js
```

And when you have multiple outputs:

```
task :build => Rake::FileList["config1.xml", "config2.xml"] do  
  # all that stuff is run only when the FileList above is changed
  touch 'foo1.js'
  touch 'foo2.js'
  sh "compile foo3.js"
  sh "do-anything-else foo4.js"
end
```

Run it using:

```
rake build
```

Comment: question: How do I make another task dependent on it? LIke this? task :foo => 'foo.js' do ..... end

Comment: I think something like this: `task build: ["foo.js"]` or if that's about an another file: `file "somethingelse.js" => "foo.js"` (*actually your `task :foo` should work just fine*)

Comment: Ok, how about when I have multiple output files? How would I do this?

Comment: You can try something like this: `task update_lots_of_files: Rake::FileList[...]`. The task will be called only when the file list is changed, and inside the task you can update as many files as you need.

Comment: So, then no need to specify the output files? If so how?

Comment: No need to specify them, just create/update them inside the task. Thus when the input files are changed running `rake update_lots_of_files` will perform its body and regenerate the output, but when the input is not changed the task body will not be run at all, so nothing will be regenerated.

Comment: I've added an example to the answer.

Comment: Doesn't quite work for multiple outputs. I just tested it, and it always touches the files foo1.js and foo2.js. I want something to skip the entire task if they are up to date.

Comment: Yep, you are right it doesn't :(. So I think there are 2 options: 1) define something like `file 'status.txt' => FileList[inputs and outputs]`, if your output files are never overwritten after the generation then it should do the trick I think. *(touch the `status.txt` in the task body)*

Comment: 2) just manually check the modification time in the task body, but that's not too nice. E.g. `File.mtime(target) > File.mtime(source)` for all files.